# Having trouble with this javascript and php cookie code

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

Here is what I am trying to do: Create a cookie onclick using php and javascript. The code I am using (below) doesn't work, because I don't really know what I am doing. I need it to be used across my domain, and expire in five minutes. Can someone help me correct this snippet? Thanks.

```
<?php
// name of the cookie
$cookie_name = 'testcookie';

// expires in five minutes, also the value of the cookie
$cookie_expire_time = time() + 300;

// check if cookie is set
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
// if NOT set
echo 'Cookie is NOT set. <a href="https://MyTestPage.com/" onClick="window.open(\'https://google.com/\'); setCookie(\''.$cookie_name.'\', \''.$cookie_expire_time.'\', '.$cookie_expire-time.');">Click here to set the cookie, reload the page, and open google in a new tab.</a>';
} else {
// if IS set
echo 'Cookie IS set now.';
}
echo '<script>
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var expires = "expires="'.$cookie_expire_time.';
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
</script>';
?>
```

My original test snippet worked (below), just can't get the first example to work how this one did. This one expires in 30 days. How can I pass an expiration in minutes using PHP?

```
<?php
$cookie_name = 'testcookie2';
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
echo 'Cookie is NOT set. <a href="https://MyTestPage.com/" onClick="window.open(\'https://google.com/\'); setCookie(\'testcookie2\', \'yes\', 30);">Click here to set the cookie, reload the page, and open google in a new tab.</a>';
} else {
echo 'Cookie IS set now.';
}
echo '<script>
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
</script>';
?>
```

Comment: unusual to want a cookie for such a short amount of time, have you considered sessions?

Comment: Are you using JS to set the cookie of PHP. Right now it looks like both. Best to pick one. Likewise what are you seeing that is not working compared to what you expect?

Comment: expires needs a [UTCString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString), now you have an integer (the timestamp)

Comment: What part of the code doesn't work as expected, can't test it at the moment?

Comment: php is not my language, but I had to ask:  Is the hyphen allowed in a variable name?  How is that distinguished from minus?   Having said that, you could write diagnostics into the error log to see how far this is getting.

Comment: @Jeff How should I fix that? Thanks.

Comment: @IdontDownVote Well, if I can get this to work, I will consider learning about sessions. Thanks.

Comment: @nerdlyist I am open to learning an all php method, just not sure where to start with that yet. Thanks.

Comment: @RufusVS Sorry, hyphen is a mis-type. Thanks.

Comment: @Jeff How do I set the value of the cookie to the timestamp integer corresponding to when the link was clicked? I will pass this value from the cookie to a timer on another page. Thanks?

Answer (score 2):

To do this in PHP you need to call `setCookie`

```
<?php
$CookieName = "userName";
$userName = "Test";
$expireAt = time() + 300;
//setcookie(name, value, expire, path, domain, secure, httponly);

setcookie($CookieName, $userName, $expireAt, "/");
```

More here http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Or you can use js which you essentially have but it is wrapped in a function that is not called at least not that I can tell. So if you did something like the below it just sets it when the page loads.

```
<script>
    var minutes = 5;
    var dt = new Date();

    var expireAt = new Date(dt.getTime() + minutes*60000);

    document.cookie = "username=John Doe; expires=${expireAt}; path=/";
</script>
```

**Edit**

I believe you want to set variables in PHP and then put that in the js script. This can be done and you were close.

If this is the page you are outputting which it appears to be then you can drop in and out of `php`

```
<?php
    //You are doing PHP here
    $CookieName = "userName";
    $userName = "Test";
    $expireAt = time() + 300;
    //This is stopping the php interpreter
?>
<!-- Here is html-->
<script>    
    //This is js on that html the <?= > opens php and you can access variables
    document.cookie = `<?=$CookieName?>=<?=$userName?>; expires=<?=$expireAt?>; path=/`;
</script>
```

Comment: I want to use php to pass address and other info to the link and cookie dynamically, that is why I am trying to get this code to work. If I can get my code to work first, then I can play around with other options. I used to know more about this stuff, but it's been a long while. That having been said, I will have a much better understanding of what I need to do by getting my example to work first. Thanks.

Comment: Can I use php to set a cookie onclick? I don't want the cookie unless the link is clicked...

Comment: I have adjusted the included code above. How can I pass the needed info to trigger onclick? Thanks.

Comment: If you want onclick just go with the js way for cookies. PHP cannot react to anything in the browser it is server side. JS is client so it hear events and what not.

Comment: Are you trying to create the js script and interpolate php variables into it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks anyways everyone. I got the code working as is with just a few changes. It's "hackey", but does what I asked. Here is what I used:

```
<?php
$cookie_name = 'testcookie5';
$cookie_time = '1';
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
echo 'Cookie is NOT set. <a href="https://MyTestPage.com/" onClick="window.open(\'https://google.com/\'); setCookie(\'testcookie5\', \'\', '.$cookie_time.');">Click here to set the cookie, reload the page, and open google in a new tab.</a>';
} else {
echo 'Cookie IS set now. Value is: '.strtotime($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]).'<br />';
}
echo '<script>
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    var cevalue = d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cevalue + "; " + expires;
}
</script>';
?>
```